# Is this what they call a "Stack Overflow"?

Tags: c, arrays, stack-overflow

So I've been trying to implement Project Euler in C because I'm a masochist, but it's actually been going pretty well up until [problem 8](http://projecteuler.net/problem=8):

```
int problem_8 () {
    int max = 0;
    const char* nums[] = {"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
                        "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
                        "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
                        "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
                        "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
                        "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
                        "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
                        "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
                        "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
                        "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
                        "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
                        "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
                        "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
                        "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
                        "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
                        "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
                        "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
                        "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
                        "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
                        "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 996; i++) {
        int k = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            k *= atoi(nums[i+j]);
        }
        if (k > max)
            max = k;
    }

    return max;
}
```

This program crashes instantly when I call `problem_8()`. Google says I should create the array dynamically on the heap rather than using the stack, but I've been having trouble figuring out how to do that exactly, as I've never really gotten into dynamic memory allocation (I come from a Java background). Do I just use malloc() to allocate a kilobyte of memory for the array? How do I accomplish this?

**EDIT: So it turns out** that `const char* nums[]` should be `const char nums[]` instead, and that instead of `atoi(nums[i+j])` I should use `nums[i+j]-'0'` instead, and it works fine now. Ignore all answers that tell me to add commas to the array.

Comment: I get `warning: string length '1000' is greater than the length '509' ISO C90 compilers are required to support`. Seems a fair warning.

Comment: Add comma between your string in your string array.

Comment: @moeCake: it's a single number: "five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number", per [its full description](http://projecteuler.net/problem=8).

Comment: Even better would be `static const char* nums = ...`. And then use `nums[i] - '0'` to get the value at position `i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uh, you realize that's a 1-element array, right? So as soon as you index with anything else than 0, you're out of bounds and causing undefined behaivior. I guess you're missing commas.

I didn't read the requirements for the the problem; if it's supposed to be a single long string, then the type of `nums` is wrong. It should be an array of `char`:

```
const char nums[] = "...
```

not an array of *pointers* to `char`:

```
const char *nums[] = "...
           ^
           |
      has meaning!
```

Comment: But I thought C strings could be declared as arrays using quotations without commas, and then you could access their individual indices

Comment: It's a single number. The lines may need concatenating with "\ (but see my comment on "max string length"). (Ed.: Oops, "\ is not necessary here.)

Comment: @CoffeeMaker, using quotations without commas will result in having the compiler see the two strings as one.

Comment: Adjacent string literal auto concate in C.

Comment: It works perfectly now, guys. Everyone telling me to add commas or whatever was incorrect, because I simply made `const char* nums[]` not a pointer anymore and suddenly it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with stack overflow.

It crashes because you're accessing entries in `nums` that do not exist. 
More precisely, `nums` is an array of strings containing just *one* string, `nums[0]`.
Fix this by using `const char* nums =`.

You also need to change the `atoi` call to `nums[i+j]-'0'`.

Comment: If that were the case then it should have thrown an array out of bounds error before compiling successfully

Comment: You understand that C doesn't have exceptions, right?  And that C compilers don't "sanity check" your program, they just translate whatever you wrote directly to machine code?  There's no check on array out of bounds, it just does whatever seems easiest for the underlying machine code, which is probably "point off to random memory."

Comment: @CoffeeMaker: unfortunately, it will not! That's one of the differences between C and Java.

Answer (score 1):

The fixed version looks like this

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < 996; i++) {
    int k = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        k *= nums[i+j]-'0';
    }
    if (k > max)
        max = k;
}
...
```

And the maximum it finds is 40824.

Answer (score -2):

No, this is not **Stack Overflow** rather logical error, try adding commas.